# TortoiseHg Freeze Hang Crash

Tags: crash, mercurial, tortoisehg, freeze

What can I do if **TortoiseHg does not react anymore**?

- I tried to revert a changed file
  => nothing happens, application freezes, no message
- I opened shelve and tried to put the changed file into a new Shelf/Trashcan
  Creating a new Shelf worked, moving the file into the shelf didn't :-(
  => nothing happens, application freezes, no message

In the console window (if open...) there is a message (as long as the shelve window is not open):

```
Warte auf Sperre von Arbeitsverzeichnis von C:\... gehalten von ''
```

which means

```
Wait for lock of working directory C:\... held by ''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to delete the file "**wlock**" in the root of the working directory (`.hg\wlock`).
**Background:**
TortoiseHg creates this file in order to prevent other instances to write to the working directory at the same time (and corrupt data). After the write operations are finished it will delete the file automatically.
Sometimes the deletion of this file doesn't work. The consequence is that no instance of TortoiseHg/Mercurial is able to write anymore into this working directory. Unfortunately the timeout for an error message is set to several minutes, so the application seems to "freeze". If you kick out or rename that file in this case, TortoiseHg will proceed and work again.